# xcode issue with git and resources

Tags: xcode, git

I'm working with another developer using xcode and git. I never had this issue previoulsy but i'm seeing this problem now consistently. When I (or the other developer) add something like an image to the project, and we push it to the repo, the files and everything are pushed and everything is fine. However, the other developer will not see the file added to the project on a pull request. I have been trying to debug this for several weeks with no luck. I have my `.gitignore` file below:

```
# xcode noise
build/*
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*~
Build/
xcuserdata
*.xcuserstate
*.moved-aside
!default.pbxuser
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.perspectivev3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3


.svn

# osx noise
.DS_Store
```

Is there anything else that I could modify in it? I tried to compare this to other projects like `AFNetworking`, `SDWebImage`, etc.

Comment: Does your commit include changes to the pbxproj file? Are you pulling a branch triggering a project file mere and using a custom merge policy for pbxproj files?

Comment: it definitely pushes pbxproj files. When we pull, sometimes it has to do a merge, but never at the pbxproj level.